# How to convert a _ctypes.pycarraytype to a bytearray?

Tags: python, ctypes

I know how to store a bytearray in ctype instance

```py
import ctypes

c_char_Arr = ctypes.c_char * 4

c_char_Arr.from_buffer(bytearray([0] * 4))
```

How do I get the bytearray back from the ctype instance?

I may be doing something wrong here too since I'm sharing a `bytearray` buffer with a ctype `c_char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to the byte array.

```py
>>> import ctypes as ct
>>> c = ct.c_char * 4
>>> b = bytearray([0]*4)   # b is the reference
>>> m = c.from_buffer(b)   # m refer to the same memory
>>> b
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00')   # b before
>>> m[1]=5                       # change via m
>>> b
bytearray(b'\x00\x05\x00\x00')   # b updated
```